# Python Subprocess or BAT script splits argument on equal sign

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess, command-line-arguments

How do I add this: `-param:abc=def` as a SINGLE command line argument?

Module `subprocess` splits this up in TWO arguments by replacing the equal sign with a space.

Here is my python script:

```
import subprocess

pa=['test.bat', '--param:abc=def']
subprocess.run(pa)
```

Here is the test program test.bat:

```
@echo off
echo Test.bat
echo Arg0: %0
echo Arg1: %1
echo Arg2: %2
pause
```

and here the output:

```
Test.bat
Arg0: test.bat
Arg1: --param:abc
Arg2: def
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Because the equal sign is gone, the real app will not be started correctly. By the way, this problem also seems to happen when running on linux, with a sh script instead of a bat file.

I understand that removing the equal sign is a 'feature' in certain cases, e.g. with the `argparse` module, but in my case I need to keep the equal sign. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Windows quoting is horribly murky. If you can't avoid Windows entirely, try `'"--param:abc=def"'`

Comment: it won't work subprocess will add backslashes to escape the quotes

Comment: @tripleee double quoting will keep the equal sign, but also passes the inner quotes to the command line argument :-(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I found out that adding a space or a junk word avoids removing the = , but still adds quotes. Like: `pa=['test.bat', '-param:abc=def ']` (space after def)

Comment: You don't show us your batch. Try using `%*` in the batch.

Comment: OR, if you quote the string, use `%~1` to show it instead of `%1` (The `~` removes the outer quotes; quoting parameters is used to delimit literal strings that contain separators like spaces, as in `Program Files` for instance.)

Comment: @Magoo I edited to better show the bat file. But don't worry, I found out how to do without any bat/ps1 file at all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to .bat file hell

To preserve equal sign, you'll have to quote your argument (explained here [Preserving "=" (equal) characters in batch file parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572424/preserving-equal-characters-in-batch-file-parameters)) (`'"--param:abc=def"')`, but then `subprocess` will escape the quotes

```
Test.bat
Arg0: test.bat
Arg1: \"--param:abc=def\"
Arg2:
```

Good old `os.system` won't do that

```
import os

os.system('test.bat "--param:abc=def"')
```

result

```
Test.bat
Arg0: test.bat
Arg1: "--param:abc=def"
Arg2:
```

Damn, those quotes won't go off. Let's tweak the .bat script a little to remove them manually

```
@echo off
echo Test.bat
echo Arg0: %0
rem those 2 lines remove the quotes
set ARG1=%1
set ARG1=%ARG1:"=%

echo Arg1: %ARG1%
echo Arg2: %2
```

now it yields the proper result

```
Test.bat
Arg0: test.bat
Arg1: --param:abc=def
Arg2:
```

Alternatively, stick to `subprocess` and remove quotes AND backslashes.

Comment: the part about tweaking the bat I don't really understand

Comment: the .bat needs to be changed to remove the quotes afterwards. I have edited the .bat file so it's more clear

Comment: The alternative is to create a BAT or CMD to call the program (Pentaho) on Windows, and a sh script to call the same program on linux, but I like the idea of killing two flies with one python script. But where normally python is superior to any other OS dependent scripting language, here it is too sophisticated . . .

Comment: You are right. This is BAT file HELL. Typing in dos terminal without any python involved: `test.bat --param:abc=def` indeed removes the = sign.

Comment: yes, I was answering your question, but there's no real reason to call a .bat file from a python script (unless the .bat file is complex and you don't want to rewrite it). This is a XY problem. You can call usually your program directly from python

Comment: Good point. Instead of migrating the bat file to ps1, I will call the exe directly from python. Much easier.

Comment: The problem has over time gone away, but your answer is very informative! Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

While this is indeed mainly a batch file hell problem, Python's subprocess implementation detail is also relevant here. So I'd like to add some minor things to @jean-françois-fabre's great answer.

As said above, when using a BAT file directly, you can avoid the argument being split at equal sign by quoting it. And if you don't want the quotes later when you refer to the argument, you can simply use `%~1` instead of doing string replacement manually.

E.g. in `Test.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo Test.bat
echo Arg0: %0
echo Arg1: %~1
echo Arg2: %~2
pause
```

```
D:\3>Test.bat "abc=def" 
Test.bat
Arg0: Test.bat
Arg1: abc=def
Arg2:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

(Note that it successfully got `abc=def` as an argument, and by using `%~1` we removed the quotes too.)

Now, this is only half of the problem. The other half is on Python's side: `subprocess.run(['Test.bat', 'abc=def'])` will not work because Python won't quote argument with equal sign, and there is no way to force it to do it. (You can't manually add it, Python will escape it to `\"`.)

So you have to manually construct the whole string and either use `os.system` as said above, or simply pass it (the string, instead of a list) into `subprocess.run()` :

```py
subprocess.run('Test.bat "abc=def"')
```

Also note, never use string (instead of list) in `subprocess.run()` on unix-like system. It will cause issues. If you really want to, add `shell=True` (you can add it on Windows too).

In summary:

```py
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.run(['Test.bat', 'abc=def']) # BAD
subprocess.run(['Test.bat', '"abc=def"']) # BAD

os.system('Test.bat "abc=def"') # OK
subprocess.run('Test.bat "abc=def"') # OK
subprocess.run('Test.bat "abc=def"', shell=True) # OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, and you can use the `shlex` package to parse the string before sending it to the shell:

```py
import subprocess, shlex

pa = shlex.split('test.bat --param:abc=def')  # parse string into a list

subprocess.run(pa)
```

Some info on the `shlex` module:
It allows us to split strings using *shell-like syntax*, which is useful when working with the shell/command line. [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this after lunch. However, I am afraid that it is shlex that is causing the problem in the first place, as the underlying module in subprocess

Comment: @Roland Although the `subprocess` module does use `shlex` to parse the command and its arguments, it does not use `shlex` to split the command. Instead, it uses `str.split()` to split on whitespace and other special characters (such as the equal sign in this case).

Comment: Unfortunately, the result still has the same problem. The result of shlex.split is the same as from my original example: `['test.bat', '--param:abc=def']`

Comment: `shlex` isn't designed (or actually used) for splitting command on Windows. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html

Answer (score 0):

As Jean-Francois said, this is caused by BAT file Hell:

```
C:\>test.bat -param:abc=def
Test.bat
Arg0: test.bat
Arg1: -param:abc
Arg2: def
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Powershell does a better job, test.ps1:

```
write-host "There are a total of $($args.count) arguments"
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $args.count; $i++ ) {
    write-host "Argument  $i is $($args[$i])"
}
```

Running from the DOS prompt:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 --params:abc=def
There are a total of 1 arguments
Argument  0 is --params:abc=def
```

Conclusion:

There is nothing wrong with Python.

Because the app that I need to start from Python has a BAT startup script, I have to replace that by a Powershell version *.ps1 script.